# How to reach the aim of asynchronous request in the Tornado web service

Tags: python, web, tornado

Question: i set up a web service based on tonardo for my model. And as the request Concurrency increases, the web will easily turn down.

What i have tried: i have already tried to read some relevant code like the asynchronous framework in tornado, but i can't get the effective ideas.

The web service code as follows:

```
class mainhandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('hello')

    def post(self):
        in_data = json.loads(self.request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        res = predict(in_data)
    def set_default_headers(self):
        self.set_header('content_type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')

application = tornado.web.Application([(r'/', mainhandler)])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(port=5000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOloop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tornado, anything that is slow must be called in a coroutine with `await`. If `predict` does some I/O of its own, it should be made into a coroutine so it can do that I/O asynchronously. If it is pure computation, you should run it on a thread pool:

```
async def post(self):
    in_data = json.loads(self.request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    res = await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, predict, in_data)
```